# Customize translations

Tags: magento2, multistore, localisation, language

I'm setting up a multi-language e-commerce store and I want to customize magento2 localization.
What is the most efficient way to do it?

For example, if I have a es_ES store and I want to change "string a" in "string b", how can I do it?

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: You can see detail tutorial for it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create file **es_ES** in

> app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/i18n/es_ES.csv

Add text to the file `"string a","string b"`

Check your changes.

Comment: Does it work only when localising theme or with all strings (even module's ones)? "string a" has to be English? Sorry for the late answer and thanks for your help!